# Spotify / Spotipy web api access token authorization problem running on Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform, spotify, spotipy

Im creating a Python script which requests user data from my Spotify account.
This is the piece of my code which gets the access token:

```
def access_token():
    redirect_uri="http://localhost:8080"
    scope = 'user-read-recently-played'

    obj = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(client_id=CLIENT_ID,client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,redirect_uri=redirect_uri,scope=scope)
    token = obj.get_access_token(as_dict=False,check_cache=False)

    return token
```

Locally when my redirect_uri was `http://localhost` the script would open a webpage and I would have to copy the url and paste it as an input back in my python script in order to acquire the access token.

[screenshot of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7gt5.png)

Im obviously trying to automate this so I changed the uri to `http://localhost:8080`.
This would then open the webpage but immediately close and I would have the access token returned in my script without having to paste the url.

When I run this locally this works fine but when I run it in a Google Cloud Function it times out . I get this info log:

```
 User authentication requires interaction with your web browser. Once you enter your credentials and give authorization, you will be redirected to a url. Paste that url you were directed to to complete the authorization.
```

any suggestions to fix this as its not an error but it times out my function.